# Groovy puzzle, man!

Tags: connect-wall

This is my first crack at making a Connect Wall puzzle - I designed it to hopefully be relatively straightforward and gentle, and an introduction to this type of puzzle for new solvers like me!

To solve this puzzle, divide these words into four groups based on something they have in common. You'll find that the four groups have something in common themselves. The words aren't in any particular order.

> AROUND, BEANS, BIG, FAIL, FIGHT, GAMES, KEEP, KID, MAFIA, MICKEY,
> PLANT, POEM, QUEEN, SPREE, TEMPERATURE, WHALE.

Hint if you get stuck:

> The title might give you a clue about the partition themes.

Comment: Is this open to all or did you just want beginners to try?

Comment: @hexomino Open to everybody but I hope some beginners take a crack at it, since I don't think it's super hard as far as these types of puzzles go :)

Comment: Cool, I think I've figured it out but I can leave it until tomorrow if others want to try it first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these are the groups

> **Group 1**
>  Words associated with **Epic** - [Epic FAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure#Internet_memes), [Epic GAMES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Games), [Epic MICKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Mickey), [Epic POEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_poetry)
>  **Group 2**
>  Words associated with **Killer** - [PLANT Killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbicide), [Killer QUEEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_Queen), [SPREE Killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spree_killer), [Killer WHALE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_whale)
>  **Group 3**
>  Words associated with **Boss** - [Boss AROUND](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/boss+around), [BIG Boss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Boss_(Metal_Gear)), [Boss FIGHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boss_(video_games)), [MAFIA Boss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_boss)
>  **Group 4**
>  Words associated with **Cool** - [Cool BEANS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cool%20beans), [KEEP Cool](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep%20cool), [Cool KID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cool_Kids), [Cool TEMPERATURE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cool)

And the link between the groups is

> Epic, Killer, Boss and Cool can all be used as synonyms for "groovy"

Comment: Yup, you got it :)